# LR(1) parsing, problem with look ahead symbols

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, lr1

I understand the concept of LR(1) parsing and lookahead symbols. I have the solution to the exercise and it does not agree with my solution.

I'm trying to fill the LR(1) parsing table for the grammar below:

```
S->xAz 
S->BAx
A->Ay
A->e
B->yB
B->y
```

Ι don't have to extend the grammar since S does not appear in any right hand side of any rule.

```
First(A)=y,e
First(Ax)=x,y
First(B)=y
First(Ay)=y
```

*Lookahead symbols in brackets.*

So, I0 = Closure(S->.xAz($) , S->.BAx($) ) =

```
S->.xAz($)
S->.BAx($)
B->.yB(x,y)
B->.y(x,y)
```

When i try **GOTO(0,x)** i think that i should go to:

```
S->x.Az($)
A->.Ay(z)
A->. (z)
```

To find the lookahead symbol for A->. & A->.Ay i take First(z). But the official book solution says the lookeahead is (z,y). 
**Where does that y comes from?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: This doesn't gave anything to do with [tag:regex-lookarounds].

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [cs.se], where it was cross-posted.

Comment: Cross-post: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/117860/lr1-parsing-problem-with-look-ahead-symbols